# Add IPI tcl script while Packaging IP

Tags: tcl, vivado

How do you add a custom tcl script to handle block propagation within IPI for a custom IP? There doesn't seem to be a GUI option for it in the package IP file groups.

What I'm trying to do is add files to the name xilinx_blockdiagram_view_fileset, as shown in various component.xml files.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add custom tcl scripts, i.e.

```
set bd_pkg_dir package/bd
file mkdir $bd_pkg_dir
set bd_group [ipx::add_file_group -type xilinx_blockdiagram {} [ipx::current_core]]
file copy -force bd.tcl $bd_pkg_dir
ipx::add_file $bd_pkg_dir/bd.tcl $bd_group
```

Hope this helps for anyone.